# Simple Java- The sentinal value keeps being calculated in my count and average?

Tags: java, sum, average

For a homework assignment i need to take an unspecified number of grades( no more than 100), get the average, and display how many are above and below average. I'm trying to use a Sentinal value to exit the loop when putting in grades. And while it does exit the loop, it also takes the Sentinal value as a grade input and calculates that into the average. For example if I enter scores "50 75 100" then exit with -1. the results will display something like 74.66666666667. I can sort of see why it is doing this looking at my for loop but I'm struggling to find a way to fix it.

```
public class AnalyzeScores {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     double scores, average;
     int aboveAvg, belowAvg;
     double sum = 0;
     int count = 0;

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     double[] scoresList = new double[100];


     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         System.out.print("Enter Score " + (i + 1)  + "(negative score exits): ");
         scoresList[i] = input.nextDouble();
         sum = sum + scoresList[i];
         count++;

         if (scoresList[i] < 0) {
            average = (sum / i);
            System.out.println("average is " + average); 
            return;
         }
     }




 }

}
```

Comment: You are exiting the method without attempting to find the scores above or below average. That's why you see just your average. Without looking for answers here just think about how to traverse scoresList array and compare each element with average before returning from the method.

Comment: yea i haven't gotten to that point yet where i search for above or below average yet. i wanted to solve this other issue i was asking about before moving on to that. turns out i just needed to move a few statements around

Answer (score 1):

That's because you put -1 to your list while calculating the average. You need to check if the input value is below zero before adding it to `scoresList`.

Here is the code where this problem is fixed (but it still requires some improvements):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double scores, average;
        int aboveAvg, belowAvg;
        double sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] scoresList = new double[100];


        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Score " + (i + 1)  + "(negative score exits): ");
            double score = input.nextDouble();
            if (score >= 0) {
                scoresList[i] = score;
                sum = sum + scoresList[i];
                count++;
            }
            else break;
        }
        average = (sum / count);
        System.out.println("average is " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! it always seems so simple after someone explains it to me.

Answer (score 1):

you should move this piece of code:

```
         sum = sum + scoresList[i];
         count++;
```

from before the if condition to after the if condition.